# Date2(7) format as 'yyyy'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL I have reasonable understanding of MS Access, I am trying to move a qry from Access to a SQL data and need to format a date2(7) field to year only ‘yyyy’ and then I need to group on that field. In access I used the following ……

```
(SELECT Format([sales].[OrderDate],"yyyy") AS [Year] FROM Sales 
GROUP BY Format([sales].[OrderDate],"yyyy");
```

How do you do this in a SQL Express database??

Comment: Seems an unusual query - if you're only selecting the columns/expressions by which you're `GROUP`ing, you'd be better placed using `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you would use the [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, [sales].[OrderDate]) AS [Year] 
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, [sales].[OrderDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT year([sales].[OrderDate]) AS [Year] FROM Sales 
GROUP BY year([sales].[OrderDate])
```